# Using anaconda prompt everything works fine but when I try to use git bash and use either pip or sudo: command not found

Tags: python, git

When I run everything using the anaconda prompt I don't run into any issues. I've been trying to create a virtual environment using Git Bash, but I get error messages specifying 'command not found' when using pip or pip3. Bit confused because I have no issues using anaconda prompt. I am using Windows.

More context: When i run the command `python -m pip install virtualenv` I get "permission denied".

Answer (score 0):

```
> $LOCALAPPDATA$\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\conda activate base
```

in Git Bash.

See https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment for more details.

This assumes you are on windows & you installed conda/miniconda to the current user.

Comment: Just ran it. Returned 'bash: conda: Permission denied'

Comment: Are you on windows?  Did you install Conda for all users? or just for you?

Comment: Yes I'm on windows. I'm assuming I downloaded Conda for all users as it's my personal desktop and I'm the only user on it.

Comment: I ran the edited line and it returned ```bash: activate: command not found```